# Definir coordenadas ao abrir mapa

Tags: android, google-maps

Preciso abrir um mapa com coordenadas especificas (latitude e longitude). Esses dados eu já tenho, porém não sei como setá-los no mapa.

PS: É possível abrir direto no Maps do Google?

Comment: A sua dúvida é abrir o aplicativo *Google Maps* com esta coordenada específica ou você mesmo implementar o mapa no seu aplicativo? Para a segunda opção, acredito que [esta questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54389/4337) irá lhe responder.

Comment: Gostaria de Abrir direto no 'Google Maps', como prossigo? - Paulo Rodrigues

Comment: César, com as respostas abaixo, agora me surgiu uma outra dúvida que parece que não está na sua pergunta. Você quer abrir o Google Maps é a partir do seu aplicativo nativo, certo? Ou você tem um site mobile?

Comment: Aplicativo nativo! (do Android Studio)

Answer (score 2):

Para abrir o **Google Maps** diretamente do seu aplicativo com uma determinada coordenada, utilizando `Intent` mesmo, por exemplo.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:-19.8516098,-43.9509601?z=15"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Outros exemplos, você pode ver [aqui na documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps). Neste meu exemplo, além da latitude e longitude, também defini o *zoom*.

Answer (score 1):

Todo Marker, você tem que inserir via JS.

Como você já tem a posição, é só enviar para o javascript e pegar em uma variavel.

Ou setar direto como neste exemplo da W3Schools.

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_map_overlays_marker)

Este link abaixo é da documentação oficial do google maps.

[Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)

Answer (score 1):

Na sua atividade principal, implemente a interface **LocationListener** e copie o código abaixo na sua atividade principal.

```
public class BasicMapActivity_new extends Activity implements LocationListener {
        private LocationManager locationManager;
        private String provider;

        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabledGPS = service
        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean enabledWiFi = service
        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (!enabledGPS) {
            Toast.makeText(BasicMapActivity_new.this, "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if(!enabledWiFi){
            Toast.makeText(BasicMapActivity_new.this, "Network signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        //getCurrentLocation();

        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
            // Toast.makeText(BasicMapActivity_new.this, "Selected Provider " + provider,
            //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {

            //do something
        }
        initilizeMap();
    }
```

Em seguida, na implementação dos métodos dessa interface faça o seguinte:

```
   @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        double lat =  location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        startPerc = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(coordinate)
        .title("Current Location")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));  

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 18.0f));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
        initilizeMap();
    }
```

Por ultimo conceda as permissões necessárias no arquivo maninfest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

basta chamar
        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LatLng)
ao carregar o mapa, ou onde for necessário.
Construa um objeto LatLng que possui o ponto x e y e pronto.